# Achar ip dentro da rede

Tags: android, web-service, redes, ip

Olá, estou tentando uma solução para achar um computador especifico dentro de uma rede por uma aplicação android, para conectar a um webservice em c#... mas o problema está em achar este computador, com o ip trocando de vez em quando. O que eu poderia fazer em relação a isso?

Comment: Se o IP muda, por que não usar o hostname?

Comment: mas no ksoap2 (plugin que estou usando para conexão) eu devo colocar o ip, acho que uma solução seria achar o ip pelo hostname e depois fazer a conexão por esse ip... mas como achar ele pelo hostname? (me corrijam se eu estiver errado...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem uma classe chamada `InetAddress` que pode te ajudar:

```
InetAddress endereco = InetAddress.getByName("hostname");
String ip = endereco.getHostAddress();
```

Referência: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Comment: funcionou :) obrigado